# Linux: Parallel processes and dependencies

Tags: linux, bash, concurrency

I want to automate code uptake at my work. There are 5 stages to it in total:

1. Uptake
2. Primary compilation
3. Secondary compilation
4. Database deploy
5. Post compilation

What I wish to do is open up three GNOME terminal windows, and in the first window run just stage 1, in second window stage 2 and 3, and in third window stage 4 and 5.

Here's an example for how to launch a GNOME terminal from a terminal (And have it stay open!) :

```
gnome-terminal \
--title="UPTAKE" \
--working-directory="$DIR" \
--command="bash -c \"echo CODE UPTAKE STARTING... ; \
exec bash\"" \
```

Here's the kicker: I wish to start Stage 2 and 4 at the same time (in parallel), but run stage 3 only if stage 2 succeeds (much like the 'Stage2 && Stage3' command in Linux), and run stage 5 only if stage 4 succeeds.

I am a novice at Linux, and there seem so many ways to launch parallel processes that I don't know which to choose. And I have no idea on how to approach my task by fulfilling all of the conditions above. Any advice would be appreciated.

EDIT: Is it possible to pass signals from one existing terminal to another? (Ie. One terminal waits on another to finish a task.)

Comment: Maybe you could write some Python script to do the task...

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no access to Python. And my knowledge in Python is slightly worse off than in Linux.

Comment: This is just `stage1; (stage2 && stage3) & (stage4 && stage5)` (although in a single terminal)

Comment: Wait, what would '&' in this case do? Isn't it used to launch something in background? I don't understand the syntax.

Comment: `a & b` executes a and b in parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am a novice at Linux

So, please take one suggestion: people hate it when terminal windows pop up and disappear without a real reason. Just write a simple shell script to implement your task so that it will work in any terminal window, not just gnome-terminal.

For a start, the logic you describe is written in shell thus:

```
stage1; (stage2 && stage3) & (stage4 && stage5)
```

Comment: Correct, that seems to be the proper logic. I did not know about the '&' character, that simplifies things for me significantly. Thank you.

Comment: As for the terminals, I realize your point, but since only me will be using it, I want to try it this way to see if it's actually possible. For the sake of doing things. :)